# JavaScript Id/Class Targeting

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to know if JavaScript can set variables of separate ID's that are the same as others, but are still separated due to class/div assigning. Here's my code.

## HTML (excerpt)

```
<div id="actions">
  <a class="action" id="0"><br>0</a>
  <a class="action" id="1"><br>1</a><br>
  <a class="action" id="2"><br>2</a>
  <a class="action" id="3"><br>3</a>
</div>
<div id="status">
  <a class="status" id="0" width="100" height="50"></a>
  <a class="status" id="1" width="100" height="50"></a>
  <a class="status" id="2" width="100" height="50"></a>
  <a class="status" id="3" width="100" height="50"></a>
  <a class="status" id="4" width="100" height="50"></a>
</div>
```

## CSS (excerpt)

```
#actions  {
    position: relative;
    left: 150px;
    top: 50px;
}
.action  {
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    width: 125px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

## JavaScript (Unknown & Written attempts)

```
var wood = document.getElementByClass("actions") #nope
var actions = {
 "attack": document.getElementById("0").getElementByClassName("action"); #not even possible
```

Comment: The "id" attributes have to be unique on a document-wide basis.

Comment: Use more classes. Or data attributes. Id is supposed to identify *unique* elements, not enumerate them.

Comment: ["The value **must** be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters."](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#the-id-attribute) - JS is irrelevant. Valid HTML must not include duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the w3c spec (emphasis mine):](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#the-id-attribute)

> The value **must** be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters.

JS is irrelevant in this case. Valid HTML must not include duplicate IDs.

If you simply want to associate data or manage identifiers differently, you must use a different attribute.

I recommend using `[data-*]` attributes, especially because you can access them via the [dataset API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```
<div id="actions">
  <a class="action" data-id="0"><br>0</a>
  <a class="action" data-id="1"><br>1</a><br>
  <a class="action" data-id="2"><br>2</a>
  <a class="action" data-id="3"><br>3</a>
</div>
<div id="status">
  <a class="status" data-id="0" width="100" height="50"></a>
  <a class="status" data-id="1" width="100" height="50"></a>
  <a class="status" data-id="2" width="100" height="50"></a>
  <a class="status" data-id="3" width="100" height="50"></a>
  <a class="status" data-id="4" width="100" height="50"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I never knew about data-ids. Thanks, Bov!

Comment: @TheGamingHideout, It's just a custom [`[data-*]` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes). I could have just as easily used `[data-fizz-buzz]` for the attribute.

Comment: How can I target the individual classes (action/status) with `document.querySelector('.status')`?

Comment: @TheGamingHideout, I assume what you're trying to ask is "how can I select a status or action using the `[data-id]` attribute?" because your question as-written isn't possible. If you want to target a specific ID, you'll need to use an attribute selector such as `document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="0"]')`. If you want to just select a status, or just select an action, you'll need to include the relevant class as well: `document.querySelector('[data-id="0"].status')`.